# Where can I buy Destiny 2 Forsaken annual pass?

Tags: destiny-2

So my friend is on PS4 and he is looking to come back to Destiny 2, he owns the forsaken dlc with all past expansions. Yet whenever he or I check there is no forsaken annual pass to get the rest of the content like the season of opulence. On bungies store there is only shadowkeep dlc and its annual pass but no forsaken annual pass. When we check on the ps store it says its unavailable. So is there no way for him to get anything past forsaken?

Comment: For the PSN store, are you or your friend logged into your account? I checked the store while I was logged out, and it displayed as “unavailable” as well. When I logged in, it gave me the option to purchase

Comment: Is this the page you're looking at? https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/product/EP0002-CUSA06172_00-D2FRSANNUALPASS1